# How to change app menu title and dock title for swift script

Tags: swift, macos

I have the following simple swift script which shows an alert:

```swift
import AppKit
import Foundation

let app = NSApplication.shared

app.setActivationPolicy(.regular) // Magic to accept keyboard input and be docked!

let icon = NSImage(named: NSImage.cautionName)
let a = NSAlert()
a.messageText = "Delete the document?"
a.icon = icon
a.alertStyle = NSAlert.Style.informational
a.informativeText = "Are you sure you would like to delete the document?"
a.addButton(withTitle: "Ok")
a.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
app.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
a.runModal()
```

Running with `swift script.swift`, this shows `swift-frontend` in the menu bar as well as in the Dock.

How can I change the title and also the icon and text in the Dock?

Comment: Where are you writing code?  AppDelegate without a function?

Comment: I run that script directly over `swfit`